# regex is not working python

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling a little with this.  I have pieced together some code to get Python to Telnet/SSH to a group of switches.  It runs show ip interface brief and show run.  It then takes that creates one file per IP and combines the output from both.  I then pick it up and run regex against it to parse info for a database.  Here is the regex I used

```
([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/(\d+)/?(\d?)\W+(\S+)\W+(\S+)\W+\S+\W+(\S+)(\W+)(\S+)
```

But I would expect the right way is to use.

```
^([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/(\d+)/?(\d?)\W+(\S+)\W+(\S+)\W+\S+\W+(\S+)(\W+)(\S+)
```

A sample of the text is below.  I want it to just pickup on lines that begin with FastEthernet (Could Be GigabitEternet...)

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol

Vlan1                      192.168.3.2     YES NVRAM  up                    up      

FastEthernet0/1/2            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      

FastEthernet0/2            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      

FastEthernet0/3            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      

FastEthernet0/4            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      

FastEthernet0/5            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      

FastEthernet0/6            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      

interface FastEthernet0/3

 description Karen

 switchport mode access

 switchport port-security

 switchport port-security mac-address sticky

 no ip address

 spanning-tree portfast
```

Comment: Why don't you use a much shorter regex and just check if the line starts with `FastEthernet` or `GigabitEthernet`?

Comment: Did you set `m` flag?

Comment: You could use [`^(?:FastEthernet|GigabitEthernet).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/xNg1mr/1)

Comment: I just checked your attempt using the multiline flag, and I think @revo is right, it worked fine for me.

Comment: You should replace not word `\W` with whitespace `\s` since not word will match a lot of stuff, including punctuation.

Comment: Thank you both.  Is adding a m flag as easy as /m or something?

Comment: Python should accept the multi-line _inline modifier_ construct. Add `(?m)` to the beginning of the regex. And I think it's available as a construction flag like `flags.multi-line` - check the docs.

Comment: (?m)^([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/(\d+)/?(\d+)?\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)     This is what I ended up with.  Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me, I just had to escape the forward slashes:

```
^([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)\/(\d+)\/?(\d?)\W+(\S+)\W+(\S+)\W+\S+\W+(\S+)(\W+)(\S+)
```

Here: https://regexr.com/3o0a1

Assuming you are passing each line individually through the expression. If you are not, `^` won't work for you here.

Comment: Shouldn't need to escape forward slashes in a python regex.  See here: https://regex101.com/r/xNg1mr/2  The main issue he is facing is the lack of the multiline flag.